# marks between windows

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface, mark

If I make a mark `ma` in one split pane and then from another I try to jump to it `'a` I can't.

I guess marks are stored per-buffer.

Can I store marks per-tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use upper case or number mark: `mA`, `'A`.

`a-z` marks are stored per buffer. `A-Z0-9` are are global marks, AFAIK you can't store built-in marks per-tab.

```
                        *'* *'a* *`* *`a*
'{a-z}  `{a-z}      Jump to the mark {a-z} in the current buffer.

                        *'A* *'0* *`A* *`0*
'{A-Z0-9}  `{A-Z0-9}    To the mark {A-Z0-9} in the file where it was set (not
            a motion command when in another file).
```